# Full screen bug Raspbarr Pi javafx

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi

I was testing Digital Clock sample app and I got this problem. The javafx application is not full screen. The desktop window still visible on right side. And Taskbar is visible as well. It doesn't seem normal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi),

> the default configuration of JavaFX on the Raspberry Pi does not use X11. Instead JavaFX works directly with the display framebuffer and input devices. So you should not have the X11 desktop running when starting JavaFX

Regarding this, usually you will launch your JavaFX from the command line, without the need of X11, but you can also launch if from a terminal window in X11. It doesn't make a difference.

Also you can read:

> JavaFX on the Raspberry Pi takes over the whole screen and captures all Linux input devices

Since Digital Clock application is designed initially for 480 x 412, the rest of the screen, up till your device resolution, will be black. You can change the size of the scene, use a different color for the background, and check the differences.

The reason for the white border is due to some overscan issues with your Pi, they are not related to JavaFX. Try changing the configuration on your Pi.

Comment: I got it fixed by launching the app from terminal, not from desktop.